# Adding new item to list changes background color/creates view above previous background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Starting to add more functionality and aesthetics to an app but I'm running into an issue where every time a goal is added within the app (cog wheel in the top right->create goal) a superseding view is created in the view hierarchy with a different background color than that of the main menu. I will say I am very new to swift so I apologize for the potential ignorance. MRE:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Goal: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let time: Date
    var isCompleted = false
}

class GoalsData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var goals: [Goal] = []
}

struct MainMenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var goalsData: GoalsData
    
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color(.lightGray)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                        .frame(height:60)
                        .blendMode(.darken)
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        Text("TODAY")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(.leading)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                                .padding(.trailing)
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(goalsData.goals) { goal in
                            Button(action: {
                                markCompleted(for: goal)
                            }) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(goal.title)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(dateFormatter.string(from: goal.time))
                                    if goal.isCompleted {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteGoal) 
                        
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.black)
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
    
    func markCompleted(for goal: Goal) {
        if let index = goalsData.goals.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == goal.id }) {
            goalsData.goals[index].isCompleted.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func deleteGoal(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        goalsData.goals.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

class TimeData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Date: [String] = []
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Create goal", destination: Option1().environmentObject(TimeData()))
                 
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Option1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var goalsData: GoalsData
    @State var newGoal = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var timeData: TimeData
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter new goal", text: $newGoal)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                
                DatePicker("Reminder Time:", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                if !newGoal.isEmpty {
                    let newGoal = Goal(title: newGoal, time: selectedDate)
                    
                    goalsData.goals.append(newGoal)
                    
                    self.newGoal = ""
                }
            }) {
                Text("Set Goal")
            }
            .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var goalsData = GoalsData()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainMenuView()
                .environmentObject(goalsData)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging the code through GPT-4, changing different color parameters, going through the UI hierarchy to try and find the origin of the view, and I'm lost. Nothing has worked, and it doesn't exactly help that I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: can you show where and how you use `Option1` view.

Comment: For sure, it's accessed from within SettingsView. `struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Goal Setting", destination: Option1().environmentObject(TimeData()))
                NavigationLink("Evening Wrap-up", destination: Option2())
                NavigationLink("Option 3", destination: Option3())
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: edit your question and add the code to it, properly formatted, it is easier to read.

Comment: Like that? Sorry man, i've never asked a question on here before, not totally sure how it works.

Comment: I meant, editing the question, not the comment, it is easier to format the code there, than the comment section.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the patience.

Comment: Without something that we can compile and run, it is difficult to debug.
In `MainMenuView`, have you tried removing the `ZStack` that wraps the `List`?

Comment: I have tried removing the Zstack. I can also add my complete code to the question, I just didn't know if that was frowned upon or not.

Comment: what is usually required is to show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Something simple (not the whole kitchen sink) that just allows us to use to tests answers.

Comment: Updated, let me know if there's anything in there I could've left out. I think I got it down far enough though.

Comment: I've tested the code, all seems to work for me. I add a new `goal`, which appears in the list,
 and the colors seems to be as I expected them (blue).
 Maybe I don't understand the question well enough. I'm on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
 It could be different on older systems.

Comment: correction, the `List` goals are of dark/black color, not blue in my tests.

Comment: The concern isn't with the color of the `goal`, it's with the background of the `MainMenuView` that I colored black to make the distinction easier. When the app opens the background is black, but if you add a `goal` then return to the main menu the background is a different color, more off-white. If you swipe left and delete the `goal` the background returns to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your `List` in `MainMenuView`, to make the background the same (black) as when the app opens.

```
List {
....
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(Color.black)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much. Didn't even know that was a thing, I've got a lot to learn.